# Как удалить javascript код с сайта

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Как удалить эти файлы со своего сайта? Они находятся на других доменах?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну Вы же наверное подключаете каптчу, либо какой-то из WordPress плагинов её подключает и наверное же не просто так, не подключайте тогда.

Comment: Но он же отмечается как неиспользуемый. То есть единственный способ удалить это - найти плагин, который загружает эти файлы, и удалить этот плагин?

Comment: Отмечается в Google Page Speed? Не стоит воспринимать на 100% истиной то что пишет Вам Google Page Speed. Он у Вас в контактной форме используется внизу страницы, Вы же там видите reCaptcha, не так ли? Ну а если допустим Вы ее уберете, что конретно Вам это даст? Риск получить много спама на почту и возможный прирост в Google Page Speed на 1-2 балла?

Comment: Понял, спасибо, а что насчёт других js скриптов? Если я хочу удалить какой-то из них, мне нужно удалять плагин или есть другой способ?

Comment: Можно использовать [wp_deregister_script()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_deregister_script), но стоит учитывать, что отключив какой-то скрипт, у Вас скорее всего что-то перестанет работать.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.